# JQuery Condition If Else bug in else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide a next button `div` until the input in it is populated so I've added this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#myDiv').val().length == 0) {
            $('#next_btn').hide();  
        } else {    
            $('#next_btn').show();      
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is myDiv

```
<textarea id="myDiv"></textarea>
```

If hiding the next button `div` but when I populate the input in `#myDiv` the `#next_btn` is not showing up.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Which event handler do you use for your code snippet?

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Comment: can you share the code of myDiv

Comment: If you put a 'debugger' in the else statement is it being hit?

Comment: I have added the whole js code

Comment: Show markup as well, or better provide a fiddle.

Comment: You forgot an onchange function, see my post below

Comment: Explain to us how #myDiv is an input? Why do you name an input element myDiv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done it short way.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <input value="Test" />
</div>
<button id="next_btn">Next</button>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(function() {
    $("#myDiv input").on("keyup", function() {
        $("#next_btn").toggle($.trim(this.value).length > 0);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LYtbJ/

Answer (score 4):

### Attach a change event handler to your input

You're only initially hiding your next element. You should also recheck on every change to your input value. Try this instead:

```
$(function(){
    // bind a change event handler
    $('#myDiv').change(function(){
        this.value.length && $('#next_btn').show() || $('#next_btn').hide();
    }).change(); // set initial state
});
```

I haven't used `if` statement since you're doing simple one sentence stuff in each case. I've rather replaced it with a boolean expression. Boolean execution of the Javascript engine will ensure that only one jQuery selector will be executed, so there's also no need to cache next button element.

You can of course replace that one-liner with an `if` like so:

```
if (this.value.length)
{
    $('#next_btn').show();
}
else
{
    $('#next_btn').hide();
}
```

### Don't forget to initialize state

Attaching a change event isn't everything. You need to set initial state as well when the page loads (or is being ready). My code does that by the last call to `.change()`. This means that it first registers the handler and then invokes it as well.

### Super simplified solution: using `toggle` with Boolean parameter

The whole thing can be replaced by this:

```
$(function(){
    // bind a change event handler
    $('#myDiv').change(function(){
        $('#next_btn').toggle(!!this.value.length);
    }).change(); // set initial state
});
```

### Is change event ok?

It may not be that change event satisfies your requirements, because it fires after field looses focus. Maybe you should be using `keypress` or `keyup` events instead. But solution stays as is. Just replace event handler binding.

Comment: Or you can do it with just `$('#next_btn').toggle(this.value.length)`, It is awesome when you read jQuery docs.

Comment: @epascarello: thanks man. I edited my answer to include this example as well. I think it can't be more simplified that that.

Comment: You may also use my demo in the answer :)

Comment: @VisioN: Yes. I upvoted you. But you're having the same problem as others. You didn't initialize state at the very beginning. Your example has value in the textbox. but if it was empty, button would still be displayed... Just so you know. ;) Otherwise keyup is the event for the OP. Apparently.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik By all means your answer was good enough from the scratch. Thx for upvote, catch one from me as well ;) Regarding the initial state, of course triggering does the job, but it's rather minor.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming #myDiv is an input tag? Or there's an input inside the div? Try this:

```
 var textarea = $("#myDiv");
 textarea.change(function(){
      if(this.value.length == 0)
           textarea.hide();
      else
           textarea.show();
 });
```

That will run the if when the input *changes*. Its important to rerun the code every time you have a change because the length is changing!

(note, it might be smart to give myDiv a better name because its not really a div but a textarea.)

update to remove extra jquery selections

Comment: You can just use `this.value.length == 0` and save yourself a few function calls, by the way.

Comment: What do you mean? like !this.value.length ?

Comment: @ZekeAlexandreNierenberg: reverse statements, not condition... Check my answer and you'll see.

Comment: OK. so you need to bind the change to #myDiv. See my update I'll write in a second.

Comment: Also note this needs to come after the textarea exsists on the page, or it needs to be wrapped in the document ready thing you've already got going.

Answer (score 1):

Assusming that the input is directly inside `myDiv`, I think what you mean to do is something like:

```
if ($('#myDiv > input').val().length == 0) {
    $('#next_btn').hide();
} else {
    $('#next_btn').show();
}
```

You are trying to check the value of an input rather than a div (which isn't possible anyway as far as I know).

Or you could simplify it some more and do `!$('#myDiv > input').val()` instead of `$('#myDiv > input').val().length == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

did you place this piece of code within an onchange function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDiv').change(function() {
        if(this.value.length == 0) {
            $('#next_btn').hide();
        } else {
            $('#next_btn').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Does this work?

Comment: See comment on my answer. You can can take out use this.value.length and save some the function calls

Comment: What's the id of your input?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing your DIV (`#myDiv`) with your input button:

```
if( $('#myDiv').find('.my-input-class').val().length == 0 ) {
    $('#next_btn').hide();
} else {
    $('#next_btn').show();
}
```

In here, I assume your input has a class 'my-input-class' and use find() to grab it. Also, I assume you have an event to listen for a user typing on your input box. Cheers.